# Visual Studio: Connect MySQL database running on localhost to ASP.NET project

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, visual-studio

I am currently trying to teach myself ASP.NET, as I will need it on the job soon. For testing purpose, I want to create a simple project with 1 or 2 RazorPages, which derives data from a MySQL database on my localhost. I am using the Visual Studio Community version. I started by creating a new ASP.NET Core Web Application project, then added a "New Connection" (see screenshot)

[image]

I also installed the packages "MySqlData", "MySqlData.EntityFrameworkCore" and "MySQLConnector". In appsettings.json, I added

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
"RazorPagesPlayersContext": "server=localhost;user=root;password=password;database=players;"
```

}

and in Startup.cs, I configured

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddDbContext<RazorPagesPlayersContext>(options => options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("RazorPagesPlayersContext")));
    }
```

However, when I to go to the create page and post a new "player" into the database, I am getting error

```
ArgumentException: Connection string keyword 'server' is not supported
```

My context file looks like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using RazorPagesPlayers.Models;

namespace RazorPagesPlayers.Data
 {
public class RazorPagesPlayersContext : DbContext
   {
  
    public RazorPagesPlayersContext (DbContextOptions<RazorPagesPlayersContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    
    public DbSet<RazorPagesPlayers.Models.Player> Player { get; set; }
   }
  }
```

When I check "Connected Services", I can only see this

[image]

I can see, that the connection string of this service has nothing to do with the connection string I added in appsettings.json. When I try to change it, it will just switch back. So I am guessing the connection to MySQL failed or am I confusing things here? I am not even sure if I am looking in the right direction, but every hint would be most welcome. Thank you very much in advance

Edit: When I change the Service config in Startup.cs to

```
 services.AddDbContext<RazorPagesPlayersContext>(options => options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("RazorPagesPlayersContext")));
```

it tells me "DbContextOptionsBuilder" does not contains a defintion for 'UseMySql' and recommends to change it to UseMySQL. This however results in an error:

```
TypeLoadException: Method 'Create' in type 'MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.MySQLSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitorFactory' from assembly 'MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=8.0.22.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' does not have an implementation.
```

is there a point in installing Pomelo?

Comment: Did you configure `RazorPagesPlayersContext` as a transient type?

Comment: Not that I know of. I copied the synthax of services.AddTransient<MySqlDatabase>(...) from some tutorial in the internet (probably a bad idea). Are there other ways for the config? Thank you!

Comment: Oh, that was a good hint! I replaced it with services.AddDbContext<RazorPagesPlayersContext>(options => options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("RazorPagesPlayersContext"))); 
Now the page loads. Thanks again

Comment: If you use `UseSqlite` you are probably not calling your local MySql-Database, try something like `UseMySql`

Comment: Also are you using ASP.Net oder ASP.Net-Core? They are different things you know.

Comment: I am using ASP.Net-Core

Comment: If you are using Asp.Net core you need to install EF core MySQL package and edit the Startup.cs file like this: `services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseMySQL(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));`

Comment: Thanks everyone, problem solved, right before my patience was spent